# Trying to create a menu and I get compiler error

Tags: java

So I am making a simple menu with Option dialog, but it just does not compile, not sure why.

This is the error:

```
Inventory.java:21: error: illegal start of expression
public static String promptInventory(String MName, String[] options)
```

Not sure what to do here. Also the way I have it set up, it should cycle back to the menu each time right? But I don't think it serves my purposes...

```
  import java.util.ArrayList;
  import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
  import javax.swing.JTextArea;
  import javax.swing.JScrollPane;

    class Inventory
    {
    public static void main(String arg[])
    {
        Database db = new Database();
        Database dpl = new Database();

    final String[] MENU_OPTIONS = {"exit", "Add product", "Sell product", "Delete  product", "Modify product",
                               "Display information"};
    final String MENU_NAME = "Inventory";


    String selection = promptInventory(MENU_NAME, MENU_OPTIONS);


    public static String promptInventory(String MName, String[] options)
    {
      int selection = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, 
                                             "Enter your Transaction Type",
                                             MName,
                                             JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION,
                                             JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE,
                                             null, options, options[0] );
      return (String)options[selection];
    }   


    //logic


      switch ( selection )
      {
         case  "exit"   :
                             break;

         case  "Add product"  : 
                             break;

         case  "Sell product" : 
                             break;

      }

      String selection = promptInventory(MENU_NAME, MENU_OPTIONS);   

      }

      }
```

Comment: Move `promptInventory` out of your `main` method

Comment: You cannot define functions inside of other functions in Java (unless you declare a new class inside the function in which you put the other function - but this is useless here).

Comment: You cannot define a method inside another method, and you haven't "closed" `main`.

Comment: Thank you, I can't believe I made that mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a tool that can format/indent the code for you. That makes these kind of errors obvious.

Your `promptInventory`method is now inside the main method and that is illegal.

Your class with methods should be indented like

```
class Inventory
{
    public void method(){

    } // end of method

    public void nextMethod(){
        // No methods in here. 
    }
}// end class
```